# How do I generate public documentation for my Rails 3 REST Service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, documentation, routes

So I'm building an application in Rails 3 using Devise as my authentication mechanism.  I have all my controllers and views working.  Our web site is humming along.  Now we'd like to export our routes to 3rd party developers.  The problem is how.

Here's the list of things I think I need to figure out.

1. Third party authentication.  I am trying to get it straight in my head what I need to do.  We have an existing user base and tokens have been generated for all of them with the Devise authentication model.  Now I need to provide some kind of security.  My current line of thinking is to set up an OAuth Provider to manage private keys and then somehow set up our web app as one of the applications the 3rd party developer can gain access to.  Is that the correct line of thinking or am I over-engineering it?
2. Generate public facing documentation for our REST endpoints.  While the rake routes is nice for internal developers, I really think we need something more along the lines of swagger-ui.  the problem is rails doesn't generate the appropriate json/xml calls for swagger-ui.  Which as I understand it are required in a true REST service.  Such as resource listing, and operations listing on a resource.

Thanks in advance for any direction you can give me in these arena's!

Comment: https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely recommend OAuth if there is a security element for your users.  That is, you want someone to be able to edit multiple users details via their service then used 3-legged OAuth (Provider, User, Client).  Otherwise go for the 2-legged OAuth (Provider, Client.)

If you want to implement a 3-legged OAuth API then I wrote a tutorial which is available [here](https://github.com/Gazler/Oauth2-Tutorial).  It uses Devise and Oauth2.

As for the documentation, I would go as far as to write custom documentation instead of relying on tools.  Twitter have a very well documented API, I use that as a basis for the RESTful APIs I write.

Comment: The guide is pretty helpful.  One thing that is not clear is where to put, "oauthenticate :interactive=>false"  I tried putting it in my application_controller as I want everything to require oauth, but it doesn't recognize it.  I do want to allow logins or OAuth since my web app will use logins to talk with the API.

Comment: If you set interactive to true then it should allow both API and login access.

Comment: That's what I did.  Everything "appears" to be working.  Going to be doing some testing when our QA gets some free cycles.  This was a side project I was doing ahead of schedule.  :-P  Thanks Gazler.  I'm giving you credit, but I'll let you know if our testers find any problems!

Comment: I've gotten a little further in my work on this.  I'm encountering an issue where there are unit tests that are looking for yml files that don't exist.  client_application.yml, and a couple oauth_*.yml files.  Any idea what's going wrong here, and why those files weren't generated?

Comment: Sure, check this out, copied straight from the tutorial.  `For the purposes of this test, we will use fixtures, I recommend using factories for real testing. Grab the 4 fixtures files out of spec/fixtures (I got them from the oauth-plugin but they were not included in the generator)`

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks man I was looking under tests/ for spec/ for whatever reason so I thought they were just missing.  I went back on your mention and look harder.  Anyway, now I've only got one failing test.  So almost there!    1) Failure:
test_should_not_exchange_without_approval(RequestTokenTest) [test/unit/oauth_token_test.rb:50]:
<false> expected to be != to
<false>.

Comment: I'm going to assume for right now that I'm supposed to delete the test files since his commit said he was deleting the _spec files to make the tests less intrusive of the app and this file hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: I just realized I never got the authenticate :interactive=>false working.  I tried to add it to my BaseController as a before_filter with no luck.  What am I missing here?

Comment: It isn't a before filter.  Take a look at https://github.com/Gazler/Oauth2-Tutorial/blob/master/provider/app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb

Comment: Thanks Gazler for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

I'm biased about Swagger (I work on it at Wordnik) and will point out that we'll add ruby server support to automatically generate the description layer like we do with Scala.

Comment: The sooner it happens the better.  It seems to me all that really needs to be done is some way of generating the resources, and operations responses and swagger-ui should work.

Comment: Haven't seen any updates on this front... how are things coming along?

Comment: @Altonymous I'm working on ruby API annotation support. Follow swagger_doc on twitter for updates on that front.